# Multiple Modals in a loop showing the same information instead of different

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog

I am attempting to create a webpage that will have a bunch of cards with info from the database.

On each card will be a "More Info" button that will create a pop up modal with the same info as that card + more information. I understand I need a while loop to generate modals as well as individually give the modals different ID's.

I have done the needful using the "id" column of the database which is unique & I do get the modals when I click the button, but the only issue is, no matter which button I click, the modal is showing the information of the very last card (such as the title, field, synopsis, description).

All the cards are showing their individual information. Sounds like something is wrong with my while loop? I did check the source code & it does correctly show individual modals with their own id's  below each particular card (with the correct id such as 1,2,3,4.) Kindly assist.

```
<?php
    include("Config.php");              
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM proj");            
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die( mysqli_error($conn));         
    while($test = mysqli_fetch_array($result))                              
    {                       
    ?>                  
    <div class="card"><div class="container1">
    <div class="card-text">  
    <h4><b><?php echo $test['title']; ?></b></h4>
    <b>field: </b><?php echo $test['field']; ?></br>    
    <p><?php echo $test['synopsis']; ?></p>

  <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
  <button id="myBtn<?php echo $test['id']; ?>">More Info</button>

  <!-- The Modal -->    
  <div id="myModal<?php echo $test['id']; ?>" class="modal"> 
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">  
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h4><b><?php echo $test['title']; ?></b></h4>
        <p><b>field: </b><?php echo $test['field']; ?></p>      
        <p><?php echo $test['synopsis']; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $test['description']; ?></p>  

 <script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal<?php echo $test['id']; ?>");
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn<?php echo $test['id']; ?>");
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "NONE";
  }
}
</script>   
</div>
</div>      
</div>
</div>
</div>                      
            <?php
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem with this code is that it generates a new `script` element on every iteration of the loop, which overwrites all the variables and event listeners.

I would suggest a different way of doing this.

1. Leave the card and modal markdown in the loop
2. Add a unique id to the modals, in fact, You already have that `<div id="myModal<?php echo $test['id']; ?>"></div>`
3. Now let us add a new attribute to the buttons, like this `<button data-target="#myModal<?php echo $test['id']; ?>"></button>`
4. Remove the `script` tag from the loop, and write a new event listener for *all* buttons which will show only the modal that has `id` attribute equal to the `data-target` attribute of the button that was clicked

The final result would look like this

```
<?php
    include("Config.php");              
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM proj");            
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);         
    while($test = mysqli_fetch_array($result))                              
    {                       
    ?>                  
    <div class="card"><div class="container1">
    <div class="card-text">  
    <h4><b><?php echo $test['title']; ?></b></h4>
    <b>field: </b><?php echo $test['field']; ?></br>    
    <p><?php echo $test['synopsis']; ?></p>

  <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
  <button data-target="myModal<?php echo $test['id']; ?>" class="action-btn">More Info</button>

  <!-- The Modal -->    
  <div id="myModal<?php echo $test['id']; ?>" class="modal"> 
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">  
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h4><b><?php echo $test['title']; ?></b></h4>
        <p><b>field: </b><?php echo $test['field']; ?></p>      
        <p><?php echo $test['synopsis']; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $test['description']; ?></p>   
</div>
</div>      
</div>
</div>
</div>                      
            <?php
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>

           <script>
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".action-btn");
// Feel free to use any other way to iterate over buttons
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var modal = (document.getElementById(
      event.target.getAttribute("data-target")
    ).style.display = "block");
  });
}
// Add code to close modals
</script>
```

Note: Bootstrap provides an easier way to use modals with all this functionality available. See [Bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I have done as you suggested, even copied the script exactly as provided, however the modal refuses to even open now. I'll admit my javascript skills are lacking, so I shall read up on the Bootstrap modals link you have provided.